# Not getting order shipping address in magento2

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping-address, magento-2.1.2

trying to get the order shipping address Magento 2. I did the below code but not its not getting.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
// order id i am getting correct. 
$order_id = $order->getId();
$order->getShippingAddress();
```

Even tried with by load that order using order but still not getting

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $orderObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order');
 $order_info= $orderObj->load($order_id);
 $shippingaddress = $order_info->getShippingAddress());
 $this->logger->info($shippingaddress);
```

Comment: Which event you tried to catch?

Comment: sales_order_place_after

Comment: provide output for `var_dump($shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();)`

Comment: @DattatrayYadav still not getting the shipping address?

Comment: How about your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If our event xml is correct, our code lines should work:

*app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="order_info" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\OrderInfo" />
    </event>
</config>
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/OrderInfo.php*

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderInfo implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
            //var_dump($shippingAddress);

    }
}
```

Should be clear your Magento Cache also.

Comment: @DattatrayYadav if it works fine, please, mark this answer as accepted. That will help our community.

Comment: its works fine for me. thank you for help. accepted the ans

Comment: @DattatrayYadav that's great!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
This code doesn't work:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

Please try this:

```
$orderids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
foreach($orderids as $oid){
    $orderID = $oid;
}
```

Then load by order Id.